# What is the default React Native perspective on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, transform

When using `transform` in React Native, there is by default no perspective on iOS but there is one set on Android. See the example at https://snack.expo.io/@wcandillon/test-3d-transform

I've tried `1280`, `1280 * pixelDensity`, `1280 * pixelDensity * 5` (based on reading this file: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blame/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/BaseViewManager.java) without any success.

I'm asking because I'm applying a 3d transform that depends on the exact angle value made between view port and the perspective.
See example: https://snack.expo.io/@wcandillon/instagram-stories 
See video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aftCqtnN6Tg
Unfortunately, I'm not able to infer this angle an Android.